# .htaccess mod_rewrite http-to-https redirect working for www.example.com/index.html but not for www.example.com/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to set up http-to-https redirect on my website, which is served from a shared hosting provider, which uses the SNI extension. This is their recommended modification to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

My issue is, when I navigate to http://www.example.com/anything.html, I am correctly redirected to https://www.example.com/anything.html. However, navigation to http://www.example.com does not result in a redirection.

Is there something about the useage of %{REQUEST_URI} that prevents it from working with no path after the domain? What modification should I make for my redirection to work correctly?

Comment: This should work. You can also try: `RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]` and keep this rule as first rule.

Comment: Thank you for making me go back and check! Something must have been cached or hadn't propagated yet--going back and looking now, everything works correctly.